# Simplest way to draw graphical elements based on information from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, html, user-interface

I am trying to figure out the simplest way to draw graphical elements based on information from a MySQL database.

The information in the database looks like this:

```
x(1),0.1,0.7,0.2
z(0.5),0.2,0.3,0.5
etc...
```

I want to draw a grid of boxes. The fill in the boxes will be based on the information from the MySQL database.

I understand that I can use PHP to retrieve the information. But how do I go from retrieving the info to drawing a box? I guess what I am asking is how do you bridge the gap from server side to client side when trying to draw things. I found a bunch of code on how to display text but not how to draw boxes with different fills that change on various data.

Comment: You can use Canvas to draw using Javascript. There are plenty of tutorials if you search for it. Start by learning about Canvas and come back if you're having issues connecting the two.

Comment: Ok thanks. So I get the info from MySQL using PHP? Then use javascript to draw the Canvas using the info from PHP. I mainly want to figure out what I need to focus on learning. There are so many options out there I just want the simplest path to accomplish what I need.

Comment: Yes. Fetch the data from MySQL using PHP, it to JS and use Canvas to draw.